# Symfony services

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

Please help me to find out how I should inject buzz http bundle in my service to send request from my service.

My services.yml

```
parameters:
    app_bundle.webUrl: https://url.com/
    app_bundle.Url: https://test.com
    app_bundle.token: rerwe9888rewrjjewrwj

services:
    app_bundle.send_message:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\SendMessage
        arguments: ["%app_bundle.webUrl%, %app_bundle.Url%, %app_bundle.token%, @buzz"]
```

My AppBundle\Utils\SendMessage

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Utils;

class SendMessage
{
    /**
     * SendMessage constructor.
     *
     * @param $webUrl
     * @param $Url
     * @param $token
     * @param Browser $buzz
     */
    public function __construct($webUrl, $Url, $token, Browser $buzz)
    {
        $this->webUrl = $webUrl;
        $this->Url = $Url;
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->buzz = $buzz;
    }

    /**
     * @param $action
     * @param null $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function sendRequest($action, $data = NULL)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        );

        $response = $this->buzz->post($this->Url . $this->token . '/' . $action, $headers, json_encode($data));

        return $response;
    }
}
```

but this caused the error:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Type error:
>   Argument 4 passed to AppBundle\Utils\SendMessage::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Buzz\Browser, none given, called in
>   /app/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 270" at
>   /app/src/AppBundle/Utils/SendMessage.php line 21
>   {"exception":"[object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every argument defined in the service configuration file must be wrapped in double quotes and separated by a comma, as the example above:

```
parameters:
    app_bundle.webUrl: https://url.com/
    app_bundle.Url: https://test.com
    app_bundle.token: rerwe9888rewrjjewrwj

services:
    app_bundle.send_message:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\SendMessage
        arguments: ["%app_bundle.webUrl%", "%app_bundle.Url%", "%app_bundle.token%", "@buzz"]
```

You provided only one string argument to the constructor: `"%app_bundle.webUrl%, %app_bundle.Url%, %app_bundle.token%, @buzz"`

Comment: Thank you very much! I need sleep I think, such a silly mistake.